# Place Text Files in another location - selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Currently my program is using txt files (filled with data) that are located in the Desktop. I am going to be sending this out to users and the text files are going to be included in a installer. When installing I don't want these files to crowd the users desktop. Any ideas on this??

Comment: How is this related to selenium or even to Python? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Kunwar, this is a somewhat subjective question, so this essentially is a subjective answer.

This is really about packaging. You've not provided any info on what your package lookslike, but in principle, why not just put the text files in the directory with your program?

your_program/inputs/*.txt

Then they will always be available to your tool. You can find the current location of your script within the script itself and build the path to the input file, no matter where the users have stored the script on their machines.

Comment: Thanks for your response Lost! I was thinking about defining a path to the text files. However I thought it wouldn't work because the path is different for every computer.